# Get Azure REST access token in Postman pre-request script

Tags: javascript, azure, postman, azure-managed-identity, azure-node-sdk

Does anyone know what is the best way to get Azure access token in Postman pre-request script? Trying to get the token for current logged in user without having to create a service principal, which is described in [How to Call the Azure REST APIs with Postman In No Time Flat](https://blog.jongallant.com/2019/04/azure-rest-apis-postman-in-no-time-flat/).

I tried in the pre-request script:

```
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
function getAccessToken(){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://management.azure.com/'});
}
pm.globals.set("access_token", getAccessToken());
```

But it keeps throwing error: `There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  Error: Cannot find module 'ms-rest-azure'`. Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://community.postman.com/t/adding-external-libraries-to-postman/1971/4

Comment: why cant use use the script mentioned in the blog itself?

Comment: I have restricted access and unable to create service principal that has the access I need. Want to test locally with my credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loginWithAppServiceMSI` need to be used in the app service, it will use the [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) of the app service to get the token, in the Postman pre-request script, it does not support to use it.

> I have restricted access and unable to create service principal that has the access I need. Want to test locally with my credentials.

In this case, if you want to use your user credentials to get the token in the  pre-request script, your option is to use the [Azure AD ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

**Note:**

1. The ROPC flow is not recommended due to the security issue, you need to expose the username and password in the postman, and if your user account is MFA-enabled, it will not work.
2. To use this flow, you also need an AD App(App registration), if you don't have the permission to create one, the workaround is to use a Microsoft built-in Application e.g. Microsoft Azure PowerShell, you can use this way to have a test, but I don't recommend you to use it in the production environment.

---

Please follow the steps:

1.Change the pre-request script in the postman collection like below.

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + pm.variables.get("tenantId") + '/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    header: 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    body: {
        mode: 'urlencoded',
        urlencoded: [ 
            {key: "grant_type", value: "password", disabled: false},
            {key: "client_id", value: pm.variables.get("clientId"), disabled: false},
            {key: "username", value: pm.variables.get("username"), disabled: false},
            {key: "resource", value: pm.variables.get("resource"), disabled: false},
            {key: "password", value: pm.variables.get("password"), disabled: false}
        ]
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    pm.globals.set("bearerToken", res.json().access_token);
});
```

2.Use the Variables like below.

```
clientId
resource
subscriptionId
tenantId
username
password
```

**Note**: The `clientId` is `1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2`, which is the `clientId` of the Microsoft Application `Microsoft Azure PowerShell`, don't change it.

[image]

3.The other settings are the same as the [blog](https://blog.jongallant.com/2019/04/azure-rest-apis-postman-in-no-time-flat/) you provided, then send the request to get the resource groups, it works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Joy this is useful info to know. But unfortunately doesn't help as I have MFA turned on. On a C# console app, we can do `var token = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/")` Can we not do something similar in JS? FYI I have a C# console app with that and it works on my local machine.

Comment: @dushyantp 1.In this case, my solution is the only way. If your account is MFA-enabled, you could not get the token in the postman, because it does not allow the interactive login. 2.It is totally a different question, I am afraid you need to ask it in another post.